# Cast `T[_ <: U]` to `T[U]`

Tags: scala, covariance

I have a java type `public interface T<U>`, which is immutable and logically covariant (read-only), but invariant in scala because it is defined in Java.

Can I safely cast a `T[_ <: U]` to a `T[U]`? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> immutable and logically covariant (read-only)

Being read-only and immutable doesn't mean it's "logically covariant"! E.g. `Consumer<A>` (`A => Unit` in Scala) is read-only and immutable, but it should be contravariant. So the answer is, it depends.

> it's a collection/iterator-ish type with methods like public U next() so still covariant

To be covariant it should have no methods inspecting values of type `U` (other than using `hashCode` and `equals`), so e.g. `List.add` is OK (for immutable list), `HashSet.contains` is OK, `TreeSet.contains` isn't.

Assuming this holds, the cast is safe. Of course, there is no way for Scala's compiler to know it, so you do still need `asInstanceOf`:

```
val t1: T[SomeSubtypeOfU] = ...
val t2 = t1.asInstanceOf[T[U]]
```

You can hide it behind an implicit conversion:

```
implicit def tIsCovariant[A](x: T[_ <: A]): T[A] = x.asInstanceOf[T[A]]
```

Comment: Fair enough, however, it's a collection/iterator-ish type with methods like `public U next()` so still covariant

Answer (score 1):

If `T` is covariant (or is not annotated as such, but shoud have), then yes:

```
scala> trait T[+X]
defined trait T

scala> trait U
defined trait U

scala> val a: T[_ <: U] = null
a: T[_ <: U] = null

scala> val b: T[U] = a
b: T[U] = null
```

This is enough to show that a cast would be sound, under the assumption that Scala type system is sound.

Comment: The problem is it's a java interface `public interface T<X>`, which is considered invariant in Scala, so not marked as covariant.